# Put a default value if the string is null during deserializing

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a model like this:

```
public class Artwork
{
    public string small { get; set; }
    public string medium { get; set; }
    public string large { get; set; }
    public string @default { get; set; }
}
```

I use this model to deserialize artwork path. When one of these strings is null I want to put a default path so I can still display a picture. I tried to use some attribute from Json.NET library:

```
[DefaultValue("path/to/any/picture")]
[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate)]
```

But it does not work, when deserializing it throws an "System.NullReferenceException".

How can I manage to display these pictures when I get a path when deserializing and display a default picture when the path is null?

Comment: What's the last thing you do with `Artwork` when your c# is finished processing it?  is it part of the view model you return from your controller?  are you serializing it manually with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`?

Comment: i'm binding it in my view ({Binding artwork.medium}). Im not serializing manually, im just doing JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchArtist>(e.result), SearchArtist is another model containing Artwork

Comment: can you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: When deserializing it throws a NullReferenceException or when you access it after deserialization has completed?

Comment: Are you sure it's JSON DefaultValueAttribute and not Microsoft DefaultValueAtribute?

Comment: When i tried to diplay my picture with {Binding artwork.medium} it diplays nothing, no more Exception but i have to display a backgroud whith the artwork large attribute and for this one i have to bind it in code behind like this : BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(artwork.large, UriKind.Absolute)); This throws an Exception

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem -- `@default` gets populated correctly.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/WKDYFd

Comment: @tounin Is this WPF, Silverlight, UWP, or some other Xaml-based framework?

Comment: Its a windows phone 8 silverlight project

Comment: @tounin - note that if the JSON sets `@default` to null explicitly, e.g. `{"default":null}`, then it will still be `null`.  The default value property only controls the value when the property is not present in the JSON.  See the updated fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/WKDYFd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem doing like this

```
public class Artwork
{
    private static string defaultAtwork = "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/06/07/06/bokeh-1123696_960_720.jpg";
    private string _small = defaultAtwork;
    private string _medium = defaultAtwork;
    private string _large = defaultAtwork;
    private string _default = defaultAtwork;

    public string small
    {
        get { return _small; }
        set { _small = value; }
    } 
    ...
}

public class Album
{
    private Artwork _artwork = new Artwork();
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public Artwork artwork
    {
        get { return _artwork; }
        set { _artwork = value; }
    }
```